# How to inject constructor in controllers by unity on mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using  unity 1.1 version and i couldn't inject constructor. My code sush as:

Registering dependencies in global.asax Application_Startup method:

```
Core.Instance.Container.RegisterType<ICartBusiness, CartBusiness>();
```

Injecting constructor:

```
private ICartBusiness _business;
        public FooController(ICartBusiness business)
        { _business = business; }
```

mvc throwing this exception:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

P.S: i can't use any new version of unity because i'm using too referenced old dlls so i can't use unity.WebApi or unity.Mvc3 dlls.

How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to tell ASP.MVC to use your container to resolve them.

Create an controller factory like

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller factory which uses an <see cref="IUnityContainer"/>.
/// </summary>
public class IocControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public IocControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType != null)
            return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
        else
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

and register it via the [ControllerBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in the global.asax

```
var factory = new IocControllerFactory(_container);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
```

Every time the framework asks for a new controller it now uses your factory which uses your container.

Comment: Thank you, i added IoCControllerFactory and I set ControllerFactory in global.asax's Application_Start method. But it throw exception on resolve controller. I think, I don't register any controller to container.

Comment: Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[SampleProject.Controllers.SampleController, null]) failed: The parameter business could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor SampleProject.Controllers.SampleController(SampleProject.BusinessLayer.ICartBusiness business). (Strategy type Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy, index 2)

Comment: 1.Why you prefer to inherit from DefaultControllerFactory over using `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));`?  2.What is the need for the check `if (controllerType != null)` and why you resort to the base if it is null?