# Unity IoC Lifetime per HttpRequest for UserStore

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to clean up the default implementation of AccountController.cs that comes out of the box in the new MVC5/Owin security implementation.   I have modified my constructor to look like this:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    this.UserManager = userManager;
}
```

Also, I have created a lifetime manager for Unity that looks like this:

```
 public class HttpContextLifetimeManager<T> : LifetimeManager, IDisposable
    {
        private HttpContextBase _context = null;
        public HttpContextLifetimeManager()
        {
            _context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        }
        public HttpContextLifetimeManager(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            _context = context;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.RemoveValue();
        }
        public override object GetValue()
        {
            return _context.Items[typeof(T)];
        }
        public override void RemoveValue()
        {
            _context.Items.Remove(typeof(T));
        }
        public override void SetValue(object newValue)
        {
            _context.Items[typeof(T)] = newValue;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to write this in my UnityConfig.cs, but this is what I have so far:

```
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new RecipeManagerContext()))));
```

I did find another example (using AutoFac) that does it this way:

```
container.Register(c => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>( new RecipeManagerContext())))
                .As<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

How would I translate the above statement using Unity IoC lifetime management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach where the `UserManager` is registered for specific lifetime is correct. However, I don't understand why it even compiles, since your `HttpContextLifetimeManager` expects the `HttpContext` as a parameter.

Another issue is that your implementation is wrong. The parameterless constructor takes **current** http context, however you rather want the lifetime manager to use the context the instance is **created** on rather the one the type is **registered** on. If the parameterless constructor is used, this could lead to http context mismatch issues.

First, change your implementation to

```
public class HttpContextLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
{
 private readonly object key = new object();

 public override object GetValue()
 {
     if (HttpContext.Current != null && 
         HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(key))
         return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
     else
         return null;
 }

 public override void RemoveValue()
 {
     if (HttpContext.Current != null)
         HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(key);
 }

 public override void SetValue(object newValue)
 {
     if (HttpContext.Current != null)
         HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = newValue;
 }
}
```

and then register your type

```
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>( new HttpContextLifetimeManager() );
```

Comment: How would I think instantiate the object inside the AccountController passing along the DbContext?

Comment: Create your own constructor factory that uses unity, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649545/how-to-inject-constructor-in-controllers-by-unity-on-mvc-4 Unity will take care of resolving complete object graph.

Comment: The example you have linked shows how DI works when using an interface, which I already understand.  I'm looking to how I can instruct Unity to see what you see ObjectType to create X instance of that object.  Look at the line using Autofac above and note that it is passing in constructor parameters.

Comment: `container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>( new InjectionFactory( c => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>( new RecipeManagerContext())), new HttpContextLifetimeManager() );`

Comment: You are awesome, thanks.  I had to switch it so HttpContextLifetimeManager() was the first parameter to RegisterType, but it works and is just what I was looking for.  Checked my work and everything looks good.  Much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK in OWIN there is no static HttpContext anymore. How do you do this without a static HttpContext for OWIN then?

Comment: @IsaacLlopis: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227078/data-caching-per-request-in-owin-application/28242568#28242568