# How can I inject a string into my classes with unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a lot of classes like so `public class GetA:IGetA{}`  `public class GetB:IGetB{}` etc etc all in a particular namespace

I register them with a block of code like so

```
  container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(
                t => t.Namespace == "Getters"),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

This works perfectly well.

I now have to introduce to some of them a dependency on a certain string.

```
public class GetA:IGetA
{
   public GetA(string separator){}
}
```

The separator is the same for all of the classes that require it. How am I best to inject this dependency?

Should I inject a factory class instead? This seems more complex than I want!

Comment: Where do you resolve your classes?

Comment: The getters are constructor injected into other classes that use them. The resolution is done by unity magic.

Comment: Where are the root objects resolved?

Comment: It is in an mvc site which uses an IDependencyResolver. I never call resolve on anything, just use interfaces in constructors and the magic happens. If I am being terribly dense then please guide me to the fact you are searching for! It is all a bit black box for me...

Comment: Take a look at the answer of the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649545/how-to-inject-constructor-in-controllers-by-unity-on-mvc-4). This does not solve your issue. But if you use a controller factory, then you get to call the `Resolve` method manually to resolve the controller. There is an overload of the `Resolve` method that allows you to override dependencies. You could do something like this: `container.Resolve<HomeController>(new ParameterOverride("separator", "myvalue"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a horror scenario but this is what I have done...

I have made my getter class depend on a `Func<string>`

```
public class GetA : IGetA
{   
   private readonly string separator;

   public GetA(Func<string> separator){
     this.separator = separator();
    }
}
```

Then in my `UnityConfig.cs` I have put

```
        container.RegisterType<Func<string>>(
            new InjectionFactory(f => new Func<string>(() => "The separator... really it comes from a database call though")
                ));
```

In my test I can do 
`new GetA (() => ", ");` which maybe looks a bit funky but keeps me separate from the database call to get the separator..

I am not really happy with this as if I want a `Func<string>` elsewhere then I will step on my toes. Perhaps I do need an `IGetSeperatorFactory` but I don't want one!