# Unity - How to create controller with dependencies manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, controller, unity-container

I'm trying to create controller instance manually, but it has some dependencies by unity and now I'm just resolving all of them automatically and pass them to controller constructor

```
var c = new MyController(container.Resolve<IInterface1>(),
                         container.Resolve<IInterface2>())
```

Is it possible to create controller instance through Unity to get all dependencies automatically resolved?

Comment: Why doesn't `container.Resolve<MyConstroller>()` not work for you? Why do you need to create the controller by hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `InjectionConstructor` to archive that. For example:

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface1, Implementation1>();
container.RegisterType<IInterface2, Implementation2>();

container.RegisterType<MyController>(new InjectionConstructor(
    container.Resolve<IInterface1>(), 
    container.Resolve<IInterface2>()));
```

Then combine this approach with [ControllerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649545/how-to-inject-constructor-in-controllers-by-unity-on-mvc-4).

Comment: This simple answer lead me to the solution. Errors occurred with controller resolve, but these were swallowed by the framework. Debugging on this statement allowed me the find the exception message and fix the issue.